# Kotlin - Trying to open one app from another app on click

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I have two programs, Animations and ColorPicker1. I am trying to get ColorPicker1 to open when I click on a menu item in the Animations program. The overall goal is to add a startActivityForResult and pass some information back from the ColorPicker1 to the Animations program, but for now I am at least trying to get the program to open without crashing.

In Animations I have added the ColorPicker1 to my Manifest file

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="com.example.colorpicker1.MainActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

and under the menu item click in Animations I have used an intent to call the ColorPicker1's Main Activity

```
            access_colorpicker -> {
                cb!!.setStyle(ChalkBoard.COLORPICKER)
                val intent = Intent("com.example.colorpicker1.MainActivity")
                startActivity(intent)
                return true
            }
```

However when I click on the menu item to access ColorPicker1 the app crashes and I am recieving an error that there is no activity file to handle the intent

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: android.matt.animation, PID: 12467
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.colorpicker1.MainActivity }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1937)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1616)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4487)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4445)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4806)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4774)
        at android.matt.animation.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.kt:116)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3450)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:368)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:108)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:108)
        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:65)
        at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:202)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:780)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:171)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:973)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:127)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1158)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3127)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4042)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

**[EDIT]**
The answer that ended up working for me is below. Also, I had to use a physical phone to test before I could pull up my ColorPicker1 app. Whenever I would try it on the Android emulator the Animations app would continue to crash with an error.

```
val launchColorPicker = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.colorpicker1")  as Intent
            startActivityForResult(launchColorPicker, 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

> In Animations I have added the ColorPicker1 to my Manifest file

No, you have not. You added an `<action>` to an existing activity in the Animations app. This has nothing to do with ColorPicker1 or any other app.

> and under the menu item click in Animations I have used an intent to call the ColorPicker1's Main Activity

No, you have not. You created an `Intent` referencing the action that you added to an existing activity in the Animations app. This has nothing to do with ColorPicker1 or any other app.

> However when I click on the menu item to access ColorPicker1 the app crashes and I am recieving an error that there is no activity file to handle the intent

That is because nothing matches the `Intent`. Your `<intent-filter>` requires one of two actions *plus* the `LAUNCHER` category. Your `Intent` has a suitable action, but it does not specify the category.

If you add the `LAUNCHER` category to the `Intent`, you should be able to launch another copy of the Animations' app's `MainActivity`. This has nothing to do with ColorPicker1 or any other app.

> I am trying to get ColorPicker1 to open when I click on a menu item in the Animations program

Your `Intent` in the Animations app needs to identify an activity *in the ColorPicker1 app*. Modifying the Animations app manifest will not help with this. What matters is what is in the manifest of the ColorPicker1 app.

Step #1: Open the manifest of ColorPicker1 in your IDE or other editor

Step #2: Look for the activity that you want to start

Step #3: Look at the `<intent-filter>` for that activity

Step #4: In the Animations app, revise your `Intent` to match that `<intent-filter>`, plus use `setPackage()` to tie the `Intent` to the application ID of the ColorPicker1 app

Comment: Here is what my new intent information looks like  ```access_colorpicker -> { cb!!.setStyle(ChalkBoard.COLORPICKER) val intent = Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN") intent.setPackage("com.example.ColorPicker1") startActivity(intent) return true}``` but I am still receiving this error when I try and access ```android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN pkg=com.example.ColorPicker1 }```

Comment: @ClarkeWoogner: Does the `<intent-filter>` on your desired activity have a `<category>` element that is something other than `DEFAULT`? If so, your `Intent` needs to have that category too.

Comment: It has a LAUNCHER category. How would I add that into the Intent category?

Comment: ```<activity android:name=".MainActivity"><intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /><category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /></intent-filter></activity>```

Comment: @ClarkeWoogner: `intent.setCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")` would be the most literal way. Do that before the `startActivity()` call.

Comment: I am receiving an unresolved reference error when using setCategory. Image added to original post

Comment: @ClarkeWoogner: Ah, sorry, [it is `addCategory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Intent#addcategory).

Comment: I am still recieving the No Activity found to handle Intent when I try and open the ColorPicker1 except now it has the action, category, and package listed. Is there anything else I can try? ```android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] pkg=com.example.ColorPicker1 }```

Comment: `com.example.ColorPicker1` does not look like an application ID. Look in your module's `build.gradle` file for the `applicationId`.

Comment: That is what is listed under applicationId though. What else could it be? Do I need to add anything else to the ColorPicker1 Main Activity to allow it to accept that it is being created?

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.colorpicker1"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

Comment: I also changed my intent from ColorPicker1 to colorpicker1 just to be on the safe side and am still receiving the same No Activity found to handle Intent error

Comment: @ClarkeWoogner "I also changed my intent from ColorPicker1 to colorpicker1 just to be on the safe side" -- most things in computer programming are case-sensitive. Nearly everything in Android app development is case-sensitive. "am still receiving the same No Activity found to handle Intent error" -- if both apps are installed on the same device (and it's not a Chrome OS device or something else weird), then I do not know what else may be going wrong. Sorry!